# Is this a safe way to test for the MediaRecorder API feature?

Tags: javascript

The [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) is available in most browsers but not Safari and IE.

Is this a "safe" way to test for it or is there a "safer"/better way?

```
function testMediaRecorder () {
       
       var isMediaRecorderSupported = false;
        
        try {
            MediaRecorder;
            isMediaRecorderSupported = true;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("no MediaRecorder");
        }
        console.log(isMediaRecorderSupported);
        return(isMediaRecorderSupported);
    }

testMediaRecorder();
```

Comment: I don't see wrong on your code. But maybe you can find a polyfill and just use it.

Comment: It works as expected, I just wondered if there was a safer way.